# Am I installing Casper FFG node correctly?

Tags: casper

After I begin running the node (normally or with the miner turned on), I see this message:

> 2018-01-02 16:47:02,428 WARNING:p2p.discovery.kademlia  recv ping from self?!

Is this what should be outputting or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same warning, but I don't believe it's of any consequence. Pyeth is known to take a long time to discover peers and begin syncing, even several hours. I've also noticed that the Casper test network is currently splintered and I'm not sure if anyone is able to connect to the main chain at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Where do we stand as of today (April 21st 2018) on the Alpha Casper testnet? None of the bootstrap nodes seems to be working

I have tried :
enode://d3260a710a752b926bb3328ebe29bfb568e4fb3b4c7ff59450738661113fb21f5efbdf42904c706a9f152275890840345a5bc990745919eeb2dfc2c481d778ee@54.167.247.63:30303

enode://a120401858c93f0be73ae7765930174689cad026df332f7e06a047ead917cee193e9210e899c3143cce55dd991493227ecea15de42aa05b9b730d2189e19b567@52.87.179.32:30303

Thanks to revert anyone